# split org-mode blocks

Tags: org-mode

Say I have an org-mode document with some block like this:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC blablabla
bla1
bla2
bla3
#+END_SRC
```

I'd like to put the point after, say, `bla2`, call some elisp and split the block like so:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC blablabla
bla1
bla2
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC blablabla
bla3
#+END_SRC
```

Does this already exist?

Answer (score 14):

The `org-babel-demarcate-block` command does this code block splitting. By default it's bound to <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-v</kbd> <kbd>C-d</kbd>.